# Carousel images on html not loading

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, materialize

I'm trying to get a carousel just like mentioned in the website of materialize

https://materializecss.com/carousel.html

However, the website generated by the below is coming up empty. I tried to shuffle the links' positions (added removed jquery cdn) but not sure where i'm going wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Top AskReDDit </title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
   
  <div class="carousel">
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#one!"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/50/df/34/50df34b9e93f30269853b96b09c37e3b.jpg"> </a>
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#two!"><img src="https://stayhipp.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/reddit.png"></a>
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#three!"><img src="https://images.discordapp.net/avatars/635458547127156767/29c03a44a8c4afdb088f0877c66831c8.png?size=512"></a>
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#four!"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/50/df/34/50df34b9e93f30269853b96b09c37e3b.jpg"></a>
  </div>

    <script type ="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.carousel').carousel();
        });

    </script>

dbsjdbsdsb

<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<!--JavaScript at end of body for optimized loading-->

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: It is not the real problem, but you should edit your post and clean up the code a bit, to avoid confusion. E.g. remove the unclosed DIV in the HEAD, remove the SCRIPT before the HTML, remove the duplicated SCRIPT. The real problem is probably "Content-Security-Policy".

Comment: thanks for the tip, kca! i tried searching for content security policy on google but couldn't find a hit, do you know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You to have call jquery before the materialize js.
Secondly write that js code only after calling libraries.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<div class="carousel">
<a class="carousel-item" href="#one!"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/50/df/34/50df34b9e93f30269853b96b09c37e3b.jpg"> </a>
<a class="carousel-item" href="#two!"><img src="https://stayhipp.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/reddit.png"></a>
<a class="carousel-item" href="#three!"><img src="https://images.discordapp.net/avatars/635458547127156767/29c03a44a8c4afdb088f0877c66831c8.png?size=512"></a>
<a class="carousel-item" href="#four!"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/50/df/34/50df34b9e93f30269853b96b09c37e3b.jpg"></a>
</div>

<!-- call jquery First -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<!--Then Initialize the carouseL-->
<script type ="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.carousel').carousel();
});
</script>

</body> 
</html>
```

Here is the working [Codepen link](https://codepen.io/jasjashim/pen/wvWLQQj).